# odoo V.9 How to make server action to execute sql query

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I want try to execute query from server action in sales order module and add the action in the "more" menu but there is found error when click the action
and I try query alone on the database and execute well
python code in server action:

```
if context.get('active_model') == 'sales.order' and context.get('active_ids'):
    self.Invoiced(cr, uid, context['active_ids'], context=context)

def Invoiced(self):
    for item in self:
        self.env.cr.execute('update sale_order_line as l set qty_invoiced = l.product_uom_qty FROM sale_order s where l.order_id = s.id and s.state = "done"')
    self.deadline = self.env.cr.fetchone()
```

#### Error:

> Odoo Server Error
>
> **SyntaxError**: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 0):

in postgresSql  you cannot use double quotes for string value :

use double quotes like this

```
SELECT 
     name as "full name" // here because i'm puttin a space inside the name of the column
```

your query should be like this :

```
self.env.cr.execute(""" 
      update sale_order_line as l set qty_invoiced = l.product_uom_qty FROM sale_order s where l.order_id = s.id and s.state = 'done' 
            """)
```

use triple quotes so you can split the query to multiple line to format your code to be more readble . sorry for my english ^^.